# Repeated column in mapping for entity in @OneToOne unidirectional mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Consider the following database structure
[image]

I need to implement **unidirectional one to one mapping** like that (structure is simplified):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_info", nullable = false)
    private CustomerInfo customerInfo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_credentials", nullable = false)
    private CustomerCredentials customerCredentials;

    //  getter, setters etc
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_info")
public class CustomerInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //  getter, setters etc
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_credentials")
public class CustomerCredentials {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //  getter, setters etc
}
```

But somehow hibernate unable to differentiate that those joins are from different tables and throws such error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.Customer column: customer_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

**Important notice**: I do not want to use `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")` because I need cascade save functionality

Comment: What happens, if you add `@OneToOne`?

Comment: @Andronicus oops, forgot to include that, thanks

Comment: Could you also post CustomerInfo and CustomerCredentials source code?

Comment: @amseager sure.

Comment: if you need cascade save functionality (save info and  credential when save a customer) you need customer_info_id and customer_creds_id in customer table

Comment: Why `mappingBy` prevents you from doing save cascade?

Comment: @imperezivan yes, it is solution but it is not what I need by design.

Comment: @Carlitos Way as far as I know `mappingBy` requires field in for example CustomerInfo so it cannot be initialized together with Customer thus there is no `customer_id` yet. Can you please explain how can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @JoinTable instead of @JoinColumn to solve your problem:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "entity") public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = CustomerInfo.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_info", inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)})
    private CustomerInfo customerInfo;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = CustomerCredentials.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_credentials", inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)})
    private CustomerCredentials customerCredentials;

    //  getter, setters etc }

@Entity @Table(name = "customer_info") public class CustomerInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //  getter, setters etc }

@Entity @Table(name = "customer_credentials") public class CustomerCredentials {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //  getter, setters etc }
```

You could change the cascade strategy to any strategy you need. I just left CascadeType.ALL there as an example.